# Magento Shopping Cart Popup

Tags: php, css, magento, web, shopping-cart

I am working on a new magento site, and there is a shopping cart link with a popup in the header, however the popup is being hidden behind the store search bar.

Can anyone help me figure this out? I've tried messing around with the z-index on the popup as well as the form to no avail

Site URL is http://www.brandography.org/healthworks

Thanks so much for all your help. I seriously mean it. This community has been really awesome.

Comment: First, your CSS comes off as an absolute mess to me with all the `float`s and `important!`s strung through the code so this was hard to decipher. Anyway, your problem is that your `container` for the header bar has a high `z-index` than your pop-up.

Comment: Thank you. A lot of this is not my CSS. This was a purchased Magento theme (definitely not going that route in the future)

Comment: Ooo yes, I've been there. It would take a lot of tweaking, but might be worth it in the long run. I mean, when I was looking at the code in Firebug, a lot of CSS rules were getting eclipsed by others because of the `important`s which is what made it hard to figure out what exactly was going on. I guess it's another case of someone having an eye for design, but not the know-how for code.

Comment: Haha actually I'm typically much more about the code myself. Magento is new to me though so I figured using a theme might help get me up to speed on the platform. Debugging it has certainly helped do that :)

Comment: Okay, well, actually what I did was remove a lot of floats and importants to make the CSS less convoluted. Let me go back and see exactly what I did. I know the search, I removed the float and made it display inline and then I removed a float on the nav header and made it full-width as well as right-aligned. That's when I found that the container had a high z-index which I turned off, and the pop-up started working.

Comment: Okay, try removing `z-index: 10000;` from `header .container`. That's what I just did on a refresh and the pop-up worked.

Comment: If you wanna add that as an answer I'll select it so you get credit for it, otherwise I can add it too.

Comment: I'll go ahead and type something up, real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specific Problem**

Both the `header .container` and search bar container had their `z-index` set high and in the latter's case, an `important!` set. Removing `z-index: 10000;` from them fixes the problem.

**Overall Problem**

User is using a theme someone created that uses terrible CSS practices and could use an overhaul to remove all the `float` and `important!` elements, but that's up to the user and obviously for another day, another question.